# How can I notify the client when async requests between microservices are done?

Tags: microservices

We have a microservice backend and upon a request from the client, we need to also invoke two other microservices, just like in the attached picture. Now I know the synchronous communication is an antipattern, but I don't know what would be the best solution for the following situation:

1. Client calls Service A, to create an asset in the database.
2. Service A has to call Service B and then Service C and those services will each create a sub-element attached to the asset created by Service A.
3. The problem is: the client needs to be notified when both Service B and Service C have created the sub-elements, and also need the details of the created elements

What I had in mind is to use async communication between the services using events, and the client would poll Servive B and Service C if the sub-elements have been created, but that raises the question of how long should it poll and how can the client know if the creation is failed with an error?

Is there a better solution?

[image: microservice communication]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with the solution you've suggested since the client shouldn't really be exposed to what happens in the downstream components / to the internal implementation details in the server ecosystem.

You could do something like firing an event back from services B & C and then listening on these events in A.

From this point you could use polling, but then you would have to persist (or cache - distributed) the full response state in A (you will probably have more then a single instance of A the client polls from), which might be fine if it is an API Gateway, but you might want to stick to HTTP APIs instead of polling.

So if A is your client facing service and you want to use a message based async solution for your downstream backends, you could use something like RabbitMQ sendAndRecive (RPC). Another alternative you can do is using something like the Atmosphere framework to hold the HTTP request context while you go to remote (B & C) services & go back to the same instance of service A.

Bottom line I would keep API communications from your client to Service A for both request and response - keeping the scope in one single place & not exposing your microservices implementation details by communicating from client to B & C.
Think of what happens when in the future you want to update service D - you don't want to change the behaviour of your client that probably don't need to be aware of it.